# PHP change text in a div using a form

Tags: php, forms

I have php file text.php in it i have

```
<div class="Text">Some text bla bla bla</div>
```

I have another file submit.php

in which i have a form

```
<form>
<textarea name="text" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
<input type="submit" value="Upload File">
</form>
```

So my question will be, how do i make the text change in text.php using my form from submit.php?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your full submit.php:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['text'])) {
    file_put_contents('text.php','<div class="Text">'.$_POST['text'].'</div>');
}
?>
<form action="submit.php" method="post">
<textarea name="text" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
<button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

Hope you are aware of the consequences in keeping the text.php file in "php". Users can type any code inside PHP tags. Better keep that file html.

Comment: It was missing ] at the end of 'text' but hat worker perfect, i know want to css the 'text' as the page im doing has black bg and the letters come out in black, i would like to make the white and center, i tried css the .Test class but it doesn't work. I also changed the text.php to an html as you suggested. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Updated the ]. To change the style, you need to add a css file in text.php using `<link>` tag, and change the style in that file. However, to just make this text white, you can use inline style, though it is against the standards. Change the line to `file_put_contents('text.php','<div style="color:white;text-align:center;">'.$_POST['text'].'</div>');`